# Is it possible to concatenate two values in an array together?

Tags: php

I’m new to PHP so this might be a very long questions. First of all I can’t normalise the database the way it has been designed it has to be kept like this. I’ll explain the scenario first: I have locations on a map, those locations can have as many products attached to them as possible. My issue is that I want to concatenate two values together in an array to make them into a string so I can store it in the db and then use it.

I’m having issues with a particular record, this record **1234** is causing me issues. As it has two Ratings attached to it but I need to concatenate them and put them into another array so I can store in my database in a particular field as strings instead of separate ints.

Below is the code, as you’ll see I did a if statement inside the code I want to use to debug what is happening in that particular record.

```
$ratingString = array();
$rating = 0;

     foreach( //not sure if this foreach is related to the question)


     if(true == isset($ratingString[$location[‘id’]])){
         echo ‘in set’;
         $ratingString[$location[‘id’]][‘ratingString’] = strval( $ratingString[$location[‘id’]][‘ratingString’]).’,’.$rating;

   }else {
        if($location[‘id’] == 1234){
        echo ‘not in set’
        $ratingString[$location[‘id’]][‘ratingString’] = $rating;
        Print_r($ratingString);

   } }
```

When I debug this, it shows me two variables in rating string.

```
Not in set 
string() “ratingString”
array(1){
    [1234] =>
    array(1) {
    [“ratingString”] =>
    int(2)
}
}
Not in set
string() “ratingString”
array(1){
    [1234] =>
    array(1) {
    [“ratingString”] =>
    int(3)
}
}
```

So what I need help with, is how could I concatenate the two so that it would be **[ratingString] => string 2,3** and how would I change my code so that it would work for all my locations and not just this particular record.

Comment: So if `$ratingString[$location['id']]` is already set, then you _append_ something to the existing value.

Comment: _"and how would I change my code so that it would work for all my locations and not just this particular record"_ - by simply removing the condition that checks for that particular ID ...? Not sure what you were trying to achieve by that to begin with.

Comment: (You are using the wrong types of quotes all over the place, btw. - all those ‘ should actually be '.)

Comment: @CBroe the quotes I know is wrong I’m doing this off my iPad so on stackoverflow I can’t get the right quotes

Comment: @CBroe Well I want to be to just have 1 ratingString that has both my values as you can see from my debugging it comes up as two rating strings instead of one

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't match the alleged output to begin with. There is no way you would be getting two separate arrays.

Comment: @CBroe I don’t know what to tell you lol I printed the ratingString out and that is what I get

Comment: Start by showing us the _actual_ code, and not something else that you typed from memory or whatever.

Comment: @CBroe this literally is the code lol I have nothing to gain from not showing you the actual code

Comment: The only outputs the code you have shown actually makes, is `in set`/ `not in set`. So the string and array debug outputs can't even come from that. And if you don't show us the actual code you actually used - then we can't possibly tell, what exactly you did wrong. So please stop it with the constant "lol"-ing, and present proper information instead. Go read [ask] and [mre], if you have not done so yet.

Comment: @CBroe Well I have now added the only other thing that is in this code which is a print statement which gives me the output that I’ve shown

Comment: This makes no sense from start to finish. You are explicitly setting `$ratingString[$location[‘id’]][‘ratingString’] = $rating;` there, so for the same ID, `isset($ratingString[$location[‘id’]])` _must_ be true, in the next loop iteration. But then it would not go into the else branch that second time - so how _could_ print_r run a second time then?

Comment: @CBroe I’m confused too so I don’t know if I should start again or not but I’m not even sure where to begin

Comment: That's up to you, but if you want our help here in the process, then please present a _proper_ [mre] of your issue. (Sample data can be presented in form of an array, instead of any actual database queries that we would not have the setup to reproduce in the first place.)